# How to parse String XML in Java

Tags: java

I have an String XML. I need to get item **ISSUCCESS** value from XML in java. But item value return null. Here is my XML Code.

1. XML

   ```
   <QRYRESULT><ISSUCCESS>N</ISSUCCESS><REASON>E002</REASON><WARNING>1. Transaction date Should be current date.11-SEP-18  E </WARNING></QRYRESULT>
   ```
2. I have written bellow code to get **ISSUCCESS** item value.

   ```
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
   InputSource is = new InputSource();
   is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(**myXML**));
   Document doc = db.parse(is);
   NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("QRYRESULT");
   for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
       Element value = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
       String ISSUCCESS = value.getAttribute("ISSUCCESS");
       System.out.println("ISSUCCESS = " + ISSUCCESS);
   }
   ```

Comment: What is the Problem with your code? `ISSUCCESS` is not an Attribute.

Comment: @Jens ISSUCCESS item It returns null

Comment: @Jens I want to get ISSUCCESS item value

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no attributes for `ISSUCCESS`

Comment: @MadProgrammer how to get ISSUCCESS item value

Comment: @EnamulHaque It's been awhile, but I imagine something like `value.getTextContent()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISSUCCESS is an Element not an attribute.

changeTo:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("QRYRESULT");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element value = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

    String ISSUCCESS = value.getElementsByTagName("ISSUCCESS").item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println("ISSUCCESS = " + ISSUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get ISSUCCESS item value using below code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(**myXML**));
Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("QRYRESULT");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node childNode = childList.item(i);
    if ("ISSUCCESS".equals(childNode.getNodeName())) {
        System.out.println(childList.item(i).getTextContent()
                                    .trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(contactsXMLstream);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("QRYRESULT");
entries=new MarketEntry[nList.getLength()];            
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
{
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        String vr= eElement.getElementsByTagName("ISSUCCESS").item(0).getTextContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(myXML)));
    // 1, get root element, get first child (ISSUCCESS), get first child (text node), get value
    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    // 2, using nodelist
    NodeList rootChildNodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
    String ISSUCCESSValue = null; 
    for (int i = 0; i < rootChildNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node childNode = rootChildNodes.item(i);
        if("ISSUCCESS".equals(childNode.getNodeName())){
            // get text node and get the value
            ISSUCCESSValue = childNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            break;
        }
    }   
    System.out.println(ISSUCCESSValue);
    // 3, using XPATH
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/QRYRESULT/ISSUCCESS/text()") // or xpath.compile("//ISSUCCESS/text()");
    String value = expr.evaluate(doc.getDocumentElement());
    System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(**myXML**));
Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("QRYRESULT");
Element qryresult = (Element) nodes.item(0);
Element success = (Element) qryresult.getElementsByTagName("ISSUCCESS").item(0);
String iSuccess=success.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
System.out.println("ISSUCCESS: " + iSuccess);
```